# What is the purpose of a backslash at the end of a line?

Tags: python, import, backslash

Just found the following module import in a Python code:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base,\
      AbstractConcreteBase
```

I am curious about the backslash `\` at the end of the first line. What's the purpose of it? Wouldn't it be the same as the following?

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, AbstractConcreteBase
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yep, it's exactly the same and this is the point of the backslash — it escapes the newline, allowing this long line to be split in two. An alternative is to use parentheses:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import (declarative_base,
      AbstractConcreteBase)
```

While this is a syntax error:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base,
      AbstractConcreteBase
```

Answer (score 1):

In the context of line-oriented text, especially source code for some programming languages, it is often used at the end of a line to indicate that the trailing newline character should be ignored, so that the following line is treated as if it were part of the current line.