# Backslashes and underscores in a loop

Tags: python, syntax

Can someone please explain what below code is doing? I don't get what is being done from 2-6th line.

```
for row in hosts_reader:
    hostname, \
    machine, \
    consul_server_mode, \
    _, _, _, \
    fixed_ip = row
    if hostname:
        all_hosts.append(Host(
            hostname.strip(),
            fixed_ip.strip(),
            devops_groups.splitlines(False),
            True if consul_server_mode == "TRUE" else False,
        ))
return all_hosts
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purpose of a backslash at the end of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060238/purpose-of-a-backslash-at-the-end-of-a-line)

Answer (score 2):

Those backslashes are simply line-breaks, used to split up a single line of code so that it looks nicer and fits on the screen.

`row` is an object (like a tuple) that contains multiple elements, and in these lines of code those elements are extracted and stored in multiple variables

For example, `hostname` will contain the first element, and `fixed_ip` the last. The three elements before the last will be ignored (`_` indicates, by convention, a variable we "dont assign a name to" and therefore also intend not to use later on)

Comment: "`_` indicates a 'variable' we dont assign a name to" might be misleading. `_` is a valid variable name and can be used later. It's just kind of a standard variable name for a value that's not used later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash allows to go to new line on the same statement. Your code is just as:

```
for row in hosts_reader:
    hostname, machine, consul_server_mode, _, _, _, fixed_ip = row
    if hostname:
        all_hosts.append(Host(
            hostname.strip(),
            fixed_ip.strip(),
            devops_groups.splitlines(False),
            True if consul_server_mode == "TRUE" else False,
        ))
return all_hosts
```

That means that `row` is a tuple and the code sets the first element of the tuple in variable `hostname`, the second in `machine` and so on. Elements from 4th to 6th are not relevant, so it uses `_` as a dummy variable / placeholder.

Comment: Doesn't really explain what that line itself does