# Python to PHP conversion socket connection

Tags: php, python, sockets

i have this script in python:

```
LOGIN_TEMPLATE = b'\xa0\x00\x00\x60%b\x00\x00\x00%b%b%b%b\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa1\xaa%b&&%b\x00Random:%b\r\n\r\n'
GET_SERIAL = b'\xa4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' \
             b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
GET_CHANNELS = b'\xa8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' \
               b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
GET_SNAPSHOT = b'\x11\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' \
               b'\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00%b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' \
               b'\x00\x00%b\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

TIMEOUT = 10

  self.serial = ''
        self.channels_count = -1
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
        self.socket.connect((ip, port))
        self.socket.send(LOGIN_TEMPLATE % (struct.pack('b', 24 + len(login) + len(password)), login.encode('ascii'),
                                           (8 - len(login)) * b'\x00', password.encode('ascii'),
                                           (8 - len(password)) * b'\x00', login.encode('ascii'),
                                           password.encode('ascii'), str(int(time.time())).encode('ascii')))
        data = self.socket.recv(128)
```

there is a way to convert in php ?

i create an example of what i try.

```
$login = 'admin';
$password ='admin';
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    define('LOGIN_TEMPLATE', '\xa0\x00\x00\x60%b\x00\x00\x00%b%b%b%b\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa1\xaa%b&&%b\x00Random:%b\r\n\r\n');

    if (!is_resource($socket)) {
        echo 'Unable to create socket: '. socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (!socket_bind($socket, '11.11.11.11', 1024)) {
        echo 'Unable to bind socket: '. socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $rval = socket_get_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR);

    if ($rval === false) {
        echo 'Unable to get socket option: '. socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . PHP_EOL;
    } else if ($rval !== 0) {
        echo 'SO_REUSEADDR is set on socket !' . PHP_EOL;
    }


    $len = strlen(LOGIN_TEMPLATE); // how to insert login e password ??


    $sendMsg = socket_send($socket, LOGIN_TEMPLATE, $len, MSG_DONTROUTE);// how to insert login e password ??

    $buf = '';
    if (false !== ($bytes = socket_recv($socket, $buf, 128, MSG_WAITALL))) {
        echo "Read $bytes bytes from socket_recv(). Closing socket...";
    } else {
        echo "socket_recv() failed; reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
    }
```

I tried to understand how to generate the LOGIN_TEMPLATE.
  but I don't understand how to interpret python code on how to generate it. can anyone help me understand how to create it?

the original python script is here:
https://gitlab.com/camshift/dahua-scanner/blob/master/utils/dahua.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
define('LOGIN_TEMPLATE', '\xa0\x00\x00\x60%b\x00\x00\x00%b%b%b%b\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa1\xaa%b&&%b\x00Random:%b\r\n\r\n');
```

write

```
define('LOGIN_TEMPLATE', "\xa0\x00\x00\x60%c\x00\x00\x00%-'\x008s%-'\x008s\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa1\xaa%s&&%s\x00Random:%d\r\n\r\n");
```

- double quoted to get the escape sequences expanded
- Python's conversion specifier [`%b`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0461) replaced as appropriate

This is just a *template* which needs to be expanded to a concrete login data packet, let's name it `$LOGIN`, with login name and password in `$login` and `$password`, respectively:

```
$LOGIN = sprintf(LOGIN_TEMPLATE, 24 + strlen($login) + strlen($password)
                               , $login, $password, $login, $password, time());
```

Comment: Thanks ! it works and only one question :
GET_CHANNELS = b'\xa8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' \
               b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
GET_SNAPSHOT = b'\x11\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' \
               b'\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00%b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' \

how to convert in php ? i don't know what is the "\" on end line

Comment: See "[What is the purpose of a backslash at the end of a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060238/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-backslash-at-the-end-of-a-line)". It allows for nicer formatting by splitting long statements. In addition, the byte-strings on the line with `\\` and the following are concatenated to one, as if both were enclosed in just one pair of quotes.

Comment: In PHP, you could also put the string parts into one string literal, or use the concatenation operator `.` between them.