# SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character (backslash)

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to run the following code from a guide book and I can't tell why I have this error. Reading to errors in this categories emphasises where the problem is (the backslash) but I'm not sure how to correct this.

```
x_range = [dataset['RM'].min(),dataset['RM'].max()]
y_range = [dataset['target'].min(),dataset['target'].max()]
scatter_plot = dataset.plot(kind='scatter', x='RM', y='target', \xlim=x_range, ylim=y_range)
meanY = scatter_plot.plot(x_range, [dataset['target'].mean(),\  dataset['target'].mean()], '--' , color='red', linewidth=1)
meanX = scatter_plot.plot([dataset['RM'].mean(),\dataset['RM'].mean()], y_range, '--', color='red', linewidth=1)
```

[image: [Code and Error]]

Comment: Remove the backslash

Comment: You need to put three back ticks before and after your code, so it doesn't get down voted, and your question wont get answered. You also should space/ clean up your code to make it more readable. It makes a huge difference, trust me.

Comment: You merged a bunch of lines that ended in `\ ` so that the line could be broken up into multiple lines. Don't do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060238/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-backslash-at-the-end-of-a-line

Answer (score 3):

In Python, we can use `\` as a line continuation character.

e.g.

```
# If you want it to be one long line.
long_str = '1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890'
```

And:

```
# If you want to split it across multiple lines.
long_str = \
    '1234567890 1234567890 1234567890' \
    ' 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890'
```

Do the same thing.

---

So, in your case, the code must have been something like this (using two lines instead of one long line):

```
scatter_plot = dataset.plot(kind='scatter', x='RM', y='target', \
    xlim=x_range, ylim=y_range)
```

If you want it to be in one line then you need to remove that `\`:

```
scatter_plot = dataset.plot(kind='scatter', x='RM', y='target', xlim=x_range, ylim=y_range)
```

---

Do the same for other lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: If this answers your question perfectly, then feel free to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and upvote.